# Viewing services on domain while under the same IP that it's pointing to.

Tags: apache, networking, redirect, dns, ip

I host various things for my projects, right from a server at my home. The question I have is, for example, say I have a webpage that's being hosted from my home server. And I've included that page into an external website hosted somewhere else. In order to see anything hosted from my location, I would need to use the local IP of the server ( 192.168.0.102 ). So, if I have this page hosted from my house, embedded into an external webpage, I can't see it, unless it's pointing to my local IP. If I point it to my local IP then everyone outside of my network can't see it.

So, to sum it up. How would I make my apache services work for me ( Me being inside the same network as the webserver ) and for the outside world? Is there some sort of redirect I can set up, so when I hit my external IP ( via Domain Name ) it will also display as my internal IP?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think this question would be better directed to [`Server Fault`](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Short and simple: You need to port forward so that your site is available from your WAN IP address, the same one shown here: http://icanhazip.com so visiting http://[wan-ip]/ should work, AFTER forwarding port 80 (and 443?) to your LAN IP (192.168.0.102).

Comment: @MarkHall - Thanks for the input, but Server Fault ( From what I believe ) is for enterprise or non-home servers.

Comment: @ionFish - I have all the correct ports forwarded from my router. My ISP blocks port 80, but I can be reached on 8010. For example http://www.minecraft.reforgedgaming.net:8010/multicraft is hosted on my home server. I can only reach it by 192.168.0.102:8010/multicraft - if I try with the domain, It times out, because I'm trying to access my WANIP from within the same network. Make sense?

Comment: Well it may be a little advanced, but you can use an external server to "proxy" port 8010 to port 80, from your house. Would be like so: `[public]>>[externalserver-domainname]>>[proxied-connection]>>[homeserver-port8010]` If you are able to physically do this, reply, and I'll create an answer with the code to do that.

Comment: @ionFish Thanks for the reply. I don't have an external server, other than a webhost server, so if this can be done using something like a .htaccess or other website files, then okay. Otherwise, I don't have anything external. 

From what I've been reading tonight, I need some sort of NAT loopback option in my router. I have a DIR-655 and I'm not seeing the option. Do you know if apache can achieve something like NAT loopback?

Comment: I can "lend you a temporary server" if you like, to host your stuff on, since I doubt it'll have a high load. Essentially on loan until you don't need it anymore. Contact me, click my username, homepage, contact page. You seem to be doing this for the learning experience, which I support fully.